# IE option title not working above selected

Tags: internet-explorer, select, title

IE11 weirdness - options with title attribute only display the tip below the selected option? In this example hover over options b and c and tip shows, but not for a. Select c and b stops showing the tip too???

```
<select name="sel">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option title="already assigned" value="a" style="background-color:gray;">a</option>
    <option title="orig selected" value="b" selected>b</option>
    <option title="already assigned" value="c" style="background-color:gray;">c</option>
</select>
```

So how do I induce IE11 to show the title tips above the selected option?

Comment: The tips show in FireFox and Chrome. I have Windows 7 - not sure if that is the limitation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does appear to be an issue with IE 11 on earlier versions of Windows. I checked Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 10, and found that tooltips were shown for all values, regardless which one was selected.

[image]

I'll file a bug for our team to consider the issue on older versions of Windows. Beyond this, we (the designers) have no control over where/whether the title window is shown. This functionality exists to assist the visually impaired in using the web, and as such the layout and placement is handled by the software itself, rather than the designer.

Comment: I have Windows 7. Wonder if that's something MS fixed in 10? Love your animated .gif example, btw. I'm in a controlled environment and have no idea when "they" will roll out Windows 10. Do you have a Windows7 box around that you could see if you get the missing tip behavior?

Comment: @gordon I checked Windows 7 and IE 11 via http://browserstack.com, and was able to confirm the issue (to be honest, it sounded familiar even before checking). It's unlikely we will do any work specifically for Windows 7, which hit end of mainstream support on January 13, 2015.

Comment: Wish there were some sort of downvote for not liking the answer, albeit the answer correctly explains the situation ;) Seems to me the hover functionality is helpful to more than just the visually impaired, and we all would benefit from a fix if anyone decided to toss a repair into a security fix for Win7 in the near future since it works in Windows 10 so the how-to is known and implemented.