# How to show tooltip on select option hover using tooltipster plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, tooltip, tooltipster

I'm new to jQuery, how can I show tooltip on select option hover using tooltipster plugin?

As title attribute not working in IE 11 for selected above options ([a bug in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571662/ie-option-title-not-working-above-selected?rq=1)). I found that from tooltipster we can achieve this. But I don't know any thing about this plugin so can anyone please provide a snippet for this.

Comment: Please can anyone answer my question

Answer (score 0):

I think that options cannot be considered as visual HTML elements whose position and dimensions can be computed by Tooltipster. They are semantic elements handled natively by the browser, it's no wonder that you get different behaviors with a title in different browsers. You should use a library like select2 to create your option list and then apply Tooltipster on its items.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Can you please provide snippet. @Evan

Comment: It's not completely straightforward, you'll have to read documentation and try for yourself.